# How do you share a link to a specific line in a webpage table that does not have an "id"?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I would like to share a link to a specific table line on a webpage. I understand it's doable when there is an "id", but there is no id. Are there any other ways to share a link?

Comment: Can you share your HTML and give more context?

Comment: Here is the page. You can see the table here. I would like to link to a specific row in the table. Is that possible?


https://www.dfps.state.tx.us/Doing_Business/Purchased_Client_Services/Residential_Child_Care_Contracts/active_contracts.asp